# Inserting into STL map structure element

Tags: c++, oop, vector, dictionary, stl

If I have a structure say,

```
struct temp
{
  int var1, var2, var3, var4, var5;
}
```

and a STL map like this:

```
map < int, temp >  mymap;
```

Now, I just want to update the value of `var2`, is it possible to do so with STL map insert function..? Can anyone guide me here please..?

Thank you

Comment: Why did you choose `std:map` ?

Comment: The way my data structures are designed, I will have to use std::map

Comment: You can do it with one line: `mymap[1].var2 = 2;`. This code will update the `var2` for the `temp structure` associated with the key 1. If this key doesn't exist yet, it will be inserted as the default-constructed value to the map and then the `var2` will be set right away.

Answer (score 1):

`Insert` is for inserting. If you just want to update then you have to `find` the struct you want to update first. E.g.

```
map < int, temp >::iterator i = mymap.find(88); // find entry with key 88
if (i != mymap.end() // did we find it?
    i->var = 99; // update vars2
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `std::map::insert` [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/):

> the insertion operation checks whether each inserted element has a
>   key equivalent to the one of an element already in the container, and
>   if so, the element is not inserted, returning an iterator to this
>   existing element

so you can use `insert` to retrieve an iterator to an already existing item.

Since there were other options mentioned including `find` and the index operator i guess this should sum it up and you can choose depending on your needs:

```
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

struct Dummy
{
    int nDummyValue;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::map<int, Dummy> Map;
    Dummy DummyInstance = { 1 };
    std::pair<std::map<int, Dummy>::iterator, bool> InsertionResult = Map.insert(std::pair<int, Dummy>(1, DummyInstance)); // Inserts {1, {1}}
    InsertionResult.first->second.nDummyValue = 2; // Sets {1, {1} to {1, {2}}
    DummyInstance.nDummyValue = 5;
    Map[5] = DummyInstance; // Adds {5, {5}}
    std::map<int, Dummy>::iterator MapIterator;
    MapIterator = Map.find(4); 
    if(MapIterator != Map.end())
        MapIterator->second.nDummyValue = 4; // Is not run because there is no element with key 5
    MapIterator = Map.find(5);
    if(MapIterator != Map.end())
        MapIterator->second.nDummyValue = 10; // Changes {5, {5}} to {5, {10}}
    for(std::map<int, Dummy>::iterator Iterator = Map.begin(); Iterator != Map.end(); ++Iterator)
        std::cout << Iterator->first << " : " << Iterator->second.nDummyValue << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;    
}
```